# Parse NSDictionary to a string with custom separators

Tags: iphone, join, nsstring, nsdictionary, separator

I have an NSMutableDictionary with some values in it, and I need to join the keys and values into a string, so

```
> name = Fred
> password = cakeismyfavoritefood
> email = myemailaddress@is.short
```

becomes `name=Fred&password=cakeismyfavoritefood&email=myemailaddress@is.short`

How can I do this? Is there a way to join `NSDictionaries` into strings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can easily do that enumerating dictionary keys and objects:

```
NSMutableString *resultString = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString* key in [yourDictionary allKeys]){
    if ([resultString length]>0)
       [resultString appendString:@"&"];
    [resultString appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [yourDict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `yourDict` be `yourDictionary`?

Comment: Also, make sure you use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` to escape special characters and spaces in your string so that you achieve a legal url.

Answer (score 6):

Quite same question as [Turning a NSDictionary into a string using blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889337/turning-a-nsdictionary-into-a-string-using-blocks)

```
NSMutableArray* parametersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[yourDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [parametersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, obj]];
}];
NSString* parameterString = [parametersArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
[parametersArray release];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that question before. (*Maybe because I asked first? :)*) I don't quite see the reason to use `alloc-init-**autorelease**` here, though. `autorelease` should only be used if it is really necessary, as it is NOT in this example (simply release the array after setting the (`NSString`).

Comment: *(oh, and as someone said in the other question, the `&` inside the "for"-method shouldn't be there)*

Comment: Exact for the autorelease (and the &). The autorelease was to have one line less, but release is better...