# Different HTTP POST behaviors from Objective C and from JQuery

Tags: jquery, objective-c, http, symfony

Hello I have a Symfony2 Controller receiving POSTs from two different clients. A web one, which sends the data using $.post (JQuery) and an Objective C iPhone APP using NSURLRequest. In both cases, I generate a JSON string and send it via POST.

Why am I getting different Request contents depending on the client? Check the following:

**JQuery approach**

```
$.post(myURL, {hist_id: 15}, function(json){}, "json");
```

gets this Request object:

```
POST /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app.php/api/saveTest HTTP/1.1
Accept:               application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:      gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:      es-es
Connection:           keep-alive
Content-Length:       17053
Content-Type:         application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:               PHPSESSID=9l9tkkcm1via94rclfshbajvj5
Host:                 127.0.0.1
Origin:               http://127.0.0.1
Referer:              http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app.php/dotest/9?t=5400&c=1&w=33&m=e&o=h&save_configuration=false
Surrogate-Capability: symfony2="ESI/1.0"
User-Agent:           Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1
X-Php-Ob-Level:       1
X-Requested-With:     XMLHttpRequest

hist_id=15 [] [] // <-- Take a look at the content of the Request. Here I get an URL style string!!
```

In this case, when I do in the Symfony controller `$this->getRequest()->get('hist_id')` I get a perfect 15.

**Objective C Approach**

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 15], @"hist_id"];
NSData* requestData = [NSJSONSerialization myDict options:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON string:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // To check that the conversion to JSON is indeed being performed perfectly!!

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"XMLHttpRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

gets this Request object:

```
POST /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app.php/api/saveTest HTTP/1.1
Accept:               application/json
Accept-Encoding:      gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:      en-us
Connection:           keep-alive
Content-Length:       15
Content-Type:         application/json
Cookie:               PHPSESSID=5l272k3858k96s3giajugslv76
Host:                 127.0.0.1
Surrogate-Capability: symfony2="ESI/1.0"
User-Agent:           PreparaTest/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0
X-Php-Ob-Level:       1

{"hist_id":"0"} [] [] // <-- Take a look at the content of the Request. Here I get a JSON plain text!!
```

In this case, when I do in the Symfony controller `$this->getRequest()->get('hist_id')` I get null.

Why is that difference? Why the content of the request is in one case an URLed string readable by the Request and Symfony2 controller and in the second case the JSON is not converted and I can't read the variable within it?

Or is it the normal way and I have to check "who" is calling me to do or not a `json_decode` of the `$request->getContent();`?

Comment: I am not familiar at all with objective-c but are you sure that the data you send are sent in the same format than when you use jQuery? I would say the issue is more related to the clients code than the server one since `$request->getContent();` is different in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your iPhone send data that can be parsed with $this->getRequest()->get('hist_id') you need to encode your data not in JSON but in **x-www-form-urlencoded**. To do so you need convert your Dictionary to String and then encode it to be correct url-encoded string. You can find info about this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html

To convert dict to string you can use code from [Turning a NSDictionary into a string using blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889337/turning-a-nsdictionary-into-a-string-using-blocks)

```
NSMutableArray* parametersArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [parametersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, obj]];
}];
NSString* parameterString = [parametersArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the answer I was looking for. So I manually need to convert my Cocoa objects to a urlencoded string. Nevertheless, I'll need to do a little more research as I need more complex data to be converted to URL. Not just a plain key/value dictionary, but also linked arrays and dictionaries. Very straightforward using JSON, but not that immediate if I need to go to URLencoded string. Any advice on that? Thanks again

Comment: Actually, take a look at this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163343/make-iphone-to-send-urlencoded-string-instead-of-json. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation of jquery.post() ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ ):

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )


dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. 
Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).
```

The fourth variable is the **expected** data type from the server. So your second variable ({hist_id: 15}) isn't being converted to json. That's why it's being sent as a normal post variable.