# Make iPhone to send URLEncoded string instead of JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, symfony, url-encoding

I have a Symfony2 server that receives HTTP POSTs from JQuery using:

```
var myJSON = {key1: "value1", key2: ["value2", "value3"]};
$.post(myURL, {myJSON}, function(json){}, "json");
```

This works perfect and internally converts the json in a Request object that, once in the Controller, I can get straightforward with `$this->getRequest()->get('key1')` or `get('key2')` obtaining some well formed PHP objects with no additional work.

So I have a complete application with JQuery and Symfony2 working this way.

Now I need to develop a mobile client using iPhone SDK and Objective C.

But all examples I am finding to do it send the JSON and convert it to PHP objects once in the server using json_decode. Those examples use this piece of code:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Value2", @"Value3", nil];
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Value1", @"key1", myArray, @"Value2"];
NSData* requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON string:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // To check that the conversion to JSON is indeed being performed perfectly!!

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"XMLHttpRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

This sends directly the JSON data to the server and the `$this->getRequest()->get('key1')` **returns null**. This approach expects to receive that JSON thata in the content body of the HTTP Request and do a PHP `json_decode` to manage the data.

Ok, I can get it modifying my "API" to check what kind of data is coming and `json_decoding` if it is JSON or the `getRequest` thing if it is URLEncode.

But before doing that workaround, isn't there an easy way to get a `JQuery` parallel conversion getting the linked `NSDictionaries` and `NSArrays` to be `URLEncoded` and sent to the server as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to get the data in the server always in the `getRequest()->get('key1')` style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works perfect and internally converts the json in a Request
>   object that, once in the Controller, I can get straightforward with
>   $this->getRequest()->get('key1') or get('key2') obtaining some well
>   formed PHP objects with no additional work.

Symfony does not internally convert your json in a Request object!
If you want one way for working with data you need to send data with only one type (json or x-www-url-encoded). I wrote you in the previous question that you can encode iOS to send data with x-www-url-encoded but you can also send JSON in jQuery.post and from iOS. And then you must implement only:

```
$data = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getContent());
```

To send JSON data in your JS you need next code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(myJSON),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){},
});
```

Comment: Thank you again!! So I have one of these two problems now: 1st-->Change all my AJAX calls (around 200) and json_decode the request->getContent(). 2nd --> As you said in both answers, to convert my Cocoa data structures (sometimes as complex as linked NSDictionarys and NSArrays) to URLEncoded strings. I'd prefer the 2nd one. But I am not finding information on how to URLEncode more complex Cocoa structures. Such as not as simple as a dictionary with some key/values pairs, but nested NSDictionary and NSArrays. Any kind of simple method to do it? Thank you again!!

Comment: Here we go! Take a look to this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166931/objective-c-how-to-convert-nested-nsdictionarys-and-nsarrays-to-urlencoded-stri