# Objective C: how to convert nested NSDictionarys and NSArrays to URLEncoded string

Tags: objective-c, url, post, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a Symfony2 project serving both a JQuery Web client and an Objective C iPhone APP.

JQuery sends properly its urlencoded data to the server. Data that is properly accessed in the Symfony2 Controller using `$this->getRequest()->get('myKey');`.

Therefor, data is sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In order not to change my Symfony Controllers (that happens to be the the whole API of my system and has around 200 AJAX calls in the form I described before), I'd like the Objective C to send the data exactly in the same way.

I have it partially gotten. I mean, I know how to convert a simple NSDictionary to a URI parameters format. This would be the code (Thanks to Michael Sivolobov).

```
NSMutableArray* parametersArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [parametersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, obj]];
}];
NSString* parameterString = [parametersArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
```

But my problem know is to know how to convert in a similar way `some more complex` data. Such as nested NSArrays and NSDictionarys (very usual when working with JSON). Anybody knows any method to convert such data to URL (key1=value1&key2=value2, etc...) in Objective C??

EDIT: example of the data I'd need to send by url.

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Value2", @"Value3", nil];
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Value1", @"key1", myArray, @"Value2"];
```

Something that in JSON would be `{"key1": "value1", "key2": ["value2", "value3"]}`

What is the best way in Objective C to get that structure and convert it to URLencode before passing it to the Http POST? I thought there would be some JSON or Cocoa method... but there is nothing...

Comment: If your data is very complex then it sounds like you should be sending JSON or XML to the server.

Comment: Are you asking for how to encode such complex data into a URI, or how to implement that encoding?  If the latter, you'd need to provide the former (or at least an example of the data to be encoded).  In fact, such an example would be good either way.

Comment: The format of the data you can URL encode is fairly restricted.  There is no "formula" for encoding an arbitrary dictionary/array nest.  For that you want to use "real" JSON, or (if you must) XML.

Comment: For those saying that sending JSON (or XML) is the answer, just to say again that I wouldn't prefer that approach as I have a whole API already working receiving parameters in the URL way (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and I wouldn't like to change it all or do a workaround to check if the request object is coming in json or in url post style. Although I'll last be doing it if I don't get an easy way to convert my nested structures to data. For an example of exactly what I need, let me just a few hours and I'll post it. Thank you all!!

Comment: Keep in mind, among other things, that the length of a URL is restricted.

Comment: Yep... I already had think of that, but I am passing certain amount of data (not little) and I am not having problems so far. Anyway I'll take it into account.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. See at the end a little example of what I'd like to convert to URL parameter. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy Cow! I had to dust off some really old PHP knowledge for this: [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

The format of a complex mixed dictionary/array objects is `base[key][key]…[key]=value`

For the JSON `{"key1": "value1", "key2": ["value2", "value3"]}`, PHP would expect `key1=value1&key2[0]=value3&key2[1]=value3` as a URL encoded string (so `key1=value1&key2%5B0%5D=value3&key2%5B1%5D=value3`).

---

For a more complex example: `{"x": {"y": ["a", "b"]}, "z" : "c"}`, PHP would expect `x[y][0]=a&x[y][1]=b&z=c`.

Comment: Ok! I think this will do it! :) Now I need the method to generate that string in Objective C. But I don't think it will cost a lot. Thank you Jeffery :)